# Create user permission with specific role?

Tags: 7, users

How do I give the "create user profile" permission to a role? I have the *manager* role and I want to give permission to to it to create an *editor* or *manager* user. I don't want to show all the roles on the user create or edit page.

Is there any module for achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [role delegation module](https://drupal.org/project/role_delegation)

> This module allows site administrators to grant some roles the
>   authority to assign selected roles to users, without them needing the
>   administer permissions permission.
>
> For each role, Role Delegation provides a new assign ROLE role
>   permission to allow the assignment of that role.

**UPDATE:**

Simply create two roles Manager and Editor role. When you create this roles, two permissions will appear on the permissions page. Assign Manager role and Editor role. Give the manager the two roles to assign. And also give the user permission to create new users.

And if you login as that user, that user will only be able to create the roles you have assigned to them.

**UPDATE 2:**

Use the module [administer user by role](https://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole). To stop the manager role from canceling or editing the adminstrator role or any other role you don't want them touching

> This module allows site builders to set up fine-grained permissions
>   for allowing users to edit and delete other users — more specific than
>   Drupal Core's all-or-nothing 'administer users' permission. It also
>   provides and enforces a 'create users' permission.

Comment: What about create new user permission?

Comment: See update to answer

Comment: ok thanks. Please see updated Question?

Comment: I checked the permission but still manager can't create user. I got access denied on admin/people/add page.

Comment: I can't give any admin permission to roles other than administrator.

Comment: At least user with manager role must have permission administer users without that, how are they expected to create users. Plus see new update

Comment: Perfect thanks. Solved by `role delegation` and `administer user by role` both.

Comment: Only edit and delete permission is there. How to add view permission?

Comment: solved by https://drupal.org/project/view_profiles_perms